# How can I stop quartus from jumping to the 'compilation report'?

Tags: quartus

When programming in VHDL I usually compile now and then to validate my code.
Quartus makes me jump to the compilation tab every time i press compile, when I just want to check for errors and fix them. This takes up alot of time and I would like to stop this but was not able to spot such feature in the settings. is there a setting hidden somewhere than can disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Tools -> Options`,
turn off `General -> Processing -> Automatically open the Report window before starting a processing task`

Comment: Actually haven't used quartus in a while now, but i'm guessing you know your stuff and this seems logical, so i'll accept this answer for now. Thx!